# How To Make Commons Configuration's setListDelimiter Work?

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I would like to use an alternate list delimiter in Apache Commons Configuration. However, despite trying a great many different ways of accessing a Configuration object and setting its list delimiter, I can never get it to actually use anything other than the default comma delimiter.

I'm using Commons Configuration version 1.8.0 with Java 1.6.0_29 on Mac OS X.

EDIT:

I need to load an XML configuration definition file that establishes a four-tier set of configuration sources:

```
  <configuration>
      <system/>
      <properties fileName="top.properties"/>
      <properties fileName="bop.properties"/>
      <properties fileName="fop.properties"/>
  </configuration>
```

... which I supply to the `DefaultConfigurationBuilder` constructor:

```
  val configBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder(configURL)
```

I've tried both overloads of `getConfiguration` on the resulting `DefaultConfigurationBuilder`. The zero-arg version is declared to return `Configuration`, not a sub-class of `AbstractConfiguration` (though it can be cast to `AbstractConfiguration`) and `Configuration` does not even define `setListDelimiter`.

Can you clarify how, given these requirements, I can get control over the list delimiter?

FOLLOW-UP:

Calling `AbstractConfiguration.setDefaultListDelimiter(listDelim)` solved the problem for me.

Randall Schulz

Answer (score 2):

To change the list delimiter for a single configuration object use the method [`setListDelimiter()`](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html#setListDelimiter%28char%29).

To change the list delimiter for all configurations, use the static method [`setDefaultListDelimiter()`](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html#setDefaultListDelimiter%28char%29).

Changing the delimiter will only affect new configuration parsings. So either [`refresh()`](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractFileConfiguration.html#refresh%28%29) your configuration or load your configuration file only after setting the list delimiter.

**Example**

ListDelimiterDemo.java

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;


public class ListDelimiterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
        AbstractFileConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        config.setListDelimiter('|');
        config.load("config.properties");

        for (Object listItem : config.getList("myprop")) {
            System.out.println(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

config.properties:

```
myprop=hello|world|!
```

Prints:

```
hello
world
!
```